# Combining queries in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

One member is part of one or many groups. One group can have one or many members.

Given one member, and the groups he is in, how can I obtain the other members in each of those groups?

```
var MemberSchema = new Schema(
{
    name: { 
        first:      { type: String },
        last:       { type: String },
    },
    groups:     [ { type: String } ],
    otherMembersInGroups: [ {
        id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Member' } ,
        name: { 
            first:      { type: String },
            last:       { type: String },
        }
    } ],
});

var query = MemberModel.findOne( { _id: objId } );
query.exec( function( err, member ) 
{
    // TODO: get all the members in all the groups that this member is in
    var otherMembersInGroups = magicHere();
    member.otherMembersInGroups = otherMembersInGroup;

    return res.send( 200, member );  
}
```

My starting point is

```
var query = MemberModel.find( { groups: "groupNamesHere" } )
```

but I don't really understand how to combine it with the above.

Also: How do I add this field to the mongoose model correctly? I tried, but there is a lot of duplication (see above). But it seems that without adding it to the model, it doesn't actually get added to the member object?

Comment: It seems the "magic" is missing. But what does your model look like? Is "groups" an array? And what do you want to do exactly? After you have one "member" do you just want to match all the other records that also have the same groups, as in some or any?

Comment: Thanks, I've added my code for the model to the above. Yes, groups is an array. After I have one "member", I want to add a field to that member which contains all the other members in the groups that this member is in. Example: You are in group x. Here are all the other members who also are in group x.

Comment: As a query result I presume that means, as opposed to actually updating the document as a whole. Is that correct?

Comment: The adding of the field to the object should happen before sending the data to the client, yes.

Answer (score 1):

For mine I would not be so formal with the "Schema" definition and handle it a little differently. Considering a schema defined like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var memberSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    first: { type: String },
    last: { type: String  }
  },
  groups: [ { type: String } ]

});

var Member = mongoose.model( 'Member', memberSchema );
```

With data like this:

```
{ 
     "_id" : ObjectId("53708c9865a6272f6e26c9bf"), 
     "groups" : [ "tennis" ], 
     "name" : { "first" : "Ted", "last" : "Logan" }, 
     "__v" : 0
}
{ 
     "_id" : ObjectId("53708cb33905d7846ee2a218"),
     "groups" : [ "tennis", "hockey" ],
     "name" : { "first" : "Bill", "last" : "Preston" }, 
     "__v" : 0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53708cd200155f916e9248f6"),
    "groups" : [ "perl", "hockey" ],
    "name" : { "first" : "Fozzie", "last" : "Bear" },
    "__v" : 0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53708ce7c95556e66ee4967f"), 
    "groups" : [ "perl", "hockey" ],
    "name" : { "first" : "Serena", "last" : "Williams" }, 
    "__v" : 0 
}
```

The rest of the operation becomes like this:

```
Member.findOne({ _id: "53708cb33905d7846ee2a218" },function(err,member) {

  Member.find({
    "groups": { "$in": member.groups },
    "_id": { "$nin": [ member._id ] }
  },function(err, others) {

    var data = {
      name: member.name,
      groups: member.groups,
      otherMembers: []
    };

    others.forEach(function(other) {
      var doc = {};
      doc.name = other.name;
      doc._id = other._id;
      data.otherMembers.push( doc );
    });

    console.log( data );

  });

});
```

Of course replacing that `console.log()` part with your actual API function. But generally a raw object has less rules to manipulate than a "schema" and is therefore just a bit easier to control your results.

Also make sure you have an index specified in that order where "groups" is the first element in order to optimize this.